# How to make highchart clickable?

Tags: html, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-click

I am rendering a chart in html div.

```
<div ng-click="changeRoute()" class="funcList">
    <div high-chart chart_object="options"></div> 
</div>
```

and in js I have -

```
 $scope.changeRoute = function(){
    $location.path(/*path i want to redirect*/);
  }
```

But, ng-click which I have given on div is not working as highcharts is overlapping div position.

So, I have written click event on highchart -

```
scope.options.chart.events.click =function(event) {
     $scope.changeRoute();
 };
```

Here what happens is - changeRoute method gets called on click of graph , but it is not redirecting it to expected route. // If i remove graph , it works good.

Any workaround for this?
(I want whole div as clickable)
Thanks

Comment: inside your controller , I created a function  function changeRoute(){
        alert("ff");
    window.location.href="http://google.com";
  }   and callled it of chart.event.click    see this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/uqpgnf8y/8/

Comment: yup.. even in your example It calls alert , but does not redirect to google

Comment: because its in iframe which is trying to access different domain, in your case it should work

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/uqpgnf8y/9/   when I call another js file(drilldown js inthis case) it opens that in frame. On your Angular App it will open on same page

Comment: ok. but why it is not working with $location.path ?

Answer (score 0):

[A fiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/uqpgnf8y/9/)

```
   function changeRoute(){
   alert("hello");
  window.location.href="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js";
}
```

called this function in load event

```
 chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events :{
                click: function(){changeRoute();}
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was issue with $location.path.
Angular doesn't always recognize that there are changes thus it never digests. 
So sometimes we have to explicitly call $scope.$apply() after $location.path .